# Difference between cfc and cfm in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Hello could someone tell me what is the difference between .cfc & .cfm in ColdFusion?
Also is there any differences related to Lucee?

I found some information here, but in my opinion it not answering about any differences for cfc & cfm if using Lucee:
https://www.learncfinaweek.com/
https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/difference-between-application-cfc-and-cfm/td-p/522654

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cfc stands for ColdFusion Component.
cfm stands for ColdFusion Markup.

There is a lot of overlap in the concepts but the important difference is that a cfm file is generally referred to as a "page" and is similiar to an html page but with access to ColdFusion tags.

This is an exmaple cfm page

```
<cfoutput>
<h1>Hi, the time is now #now()#</h1>
</cfoutput>
```

A cfc file is used to represent a single component or object. This might look like

```
component {
  public function init(){
    return this;
  }

  public function sayHi(){
    return "Hi";
  }
}
```

They serve different purposes but often they will be used together. For instance, one might handle a request with a single cfm page but then create multiple components that live in separate cfcs in order to do all the work on the page.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Is there any differences between both of using Lucee?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking but to my knowledge lucee and adobe cf treat cfms and cfcs the same.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @etchesketch's answer:

- A CFM is generally considered a layout, display, or presentation page.
- A CFC is where you create functions that contain data calls and business logic.

SomeComponent.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent>

    <!--- Create an instance of this object (CFC). --->
    <cffunction name="init" access="public" returntype="SomeComponent">
        <cfapplication name="dsn" type="string" required="true" hint="Pass the datasource name as a stirng.">
        <!--- Do not reference from shared scope variables. --->
        <cfset variables.dsn = arguments.dsn>
        <!--- Return an instance of this object (CFC). --->
        <cfreturn this>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunciton name="someData" access="public" returntype="query">
        <!--- Create the query variable in the function local scope for safe requests. --->
        <!--- Reference the data source from the component's global scope. --->
        <cfquery name="local.data" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
            <!--- Select data here. --->
        </cfquery>
        <!--- Return the data from the function. --->
        <cfreturn local.data>
    </cffunciton>

</cfcomponent>
```

some_data.cfm:

```
// Create an instance of the object (CFC).
<cfset SomeComponent = new SomeComponent("datasource")> 
// Get some data from the object. 
<cfset data = SomeComponent.someData()>

// Display the data>
<cfdump var="#data#">
```

---

**UPDATE** To Dan's point, the goal is to create reusable code. While you can reuse the content of a `CFM` file using `<cfinclude>` or `<cfmodule>`, a CFC provides an additional layer of security through encapsulation. The code in a CFC should be isolated from any shared scope variables, allowing you to test the code independently, without any application settings.

You can cache CFCs into shared scopes like `application` or `session` in order to carry the functions in memory instead of creating new objects with every request. But with this approach, you have to be careful about memory leaks through correct variable scoping.

There's a lot more, but that's the basics of it.

---

There's more information here, but it also gets into object-oriented programming which may be more than you need now.

https://www.learncfinaweek.com/course/index/section/OOP/item/OOP.html

Depending on your experience with CF, you might browse the whole site for other insight. https://www.learncfinaweek.com

Comment: I'm not downvoting this answer, but I disagree with it.  I consider cfc's to be one of the ways to write reusable code.

Comment: @DanBracuk I should have been more specific about that point.